# IF statement gives blank cells

Tags: sql, ms-access, if-statement

I have a table (Employee List) which has an employee ID, employee type and grade column. The following IF statement works, however some employees do not have a rank (blank cell instead) which means this formula brings back blank cells for them. How can I get this to bring back NONE for non-employees and employees with a blank cell as their rank, thanks.

```
IIf([Employee List].[Employer Type]="Employee",([Employee List].[Rank]),"NONE") AS Grade
```

Answer (score 0):

Just test for the right conditions:

```
IIf([Employee List].[Employer Type] = "Employee" OR
    [Employee List].[Rank] IS NULL OR
    [Employee List].[Rank] = "", [Employee List].[Rank], "NONE"
   ) AS Grade
```

Comment: Didn't work, grade still appears as blank for those with blanks as their rank. Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: @Analyst1 How blank is "blank"? This expression tests for null or empty string, but not for a rank consisting of one or more spaces - try adding a [TRIM](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/trim.php)